# How to receive function parameters for key value type functions in js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

How to receive parameters in these kind of functions?

```
     //Below function need to receive the passed parameter(id)???
  static apiConfig = {
    actions: {
      loadAllUsers: {
        method: 'get',
        url: '/api/v1/users',
        dataTransformer: (response) => {
          return new JsonApiResponseConverter(response.data).formattedResponse
        }
      }
 }
 }
```

Function is on a vuex orm model. It gets called like this from a vue component

```
 User.api().loadAllUsers(id)
```

Comment: In the code you've shown, `loadAllUsers` is a plain Javascript object, but not a `function`.

Comment: @connexo sorry updated.

Answer (score 1):

`loadAllUsers` is not a function. It's an object.
You cannot call an `loadAllUsers` in `loadAllUsers(id)`.
It will throw an error 
`loadAllUsers is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

```
loadAllUsers: function(id){
$.ajax({
method: 'get',
url: '/api/v1/users',
dataTransformer: (response) => {
  return new JsonApiResponseConverter(response.data).formattedResponse
}
})
}
```

Comment: That is not valid Javascript syntax.

Comment: `loadAllUsers` will return `undefined`.